# can I combine the edge and vertex of separate polygons into one integral model?

Tags: mesh

I needed to finish drawing the polygons to the model and I would like to combine them with the old ones, since in the game engine - at this point the joint will be visible if the polygons are even adjacent to each other. Can I somehow combine a vertex with an edge into a whole mesh?

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to see what you mean from those images and your description. You mention "drawing", but that doesn't really have any meaning in basic modelling in Blender. Are your polygon mesh and the hilighted section in your image one object? If not, you'd have to join the objects first with Ctrl-J before you can merge vertices.

Comment: @JohnEason I need there to be no orange separation in the center of the grid (photo 2). I need those polygons to merge and complement each other

Comment: Ok, but is that all one object or are there two seperate ones? I think we'd need to look at your blend file to see exactly what you mean. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page if it's not too large.

Comment: @JohnEason It's too big. A grid is one solid object. https://i.imgur.com/hwrgnTC.png

Comment: You'll have to upload it to an external site and provide a link to it in that case.

Comment: @JohnEason added under the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144361/discussion-between-maxim-r-and-john-eason).

Answer (score 0):

Enable the *Auto Merge* and the *Split Edges & Faces* options, then select all, press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, the faces are now sticking together:

[image]